# Entity Component System - Rendering approach

Tags: c++, game-engine, directx-12

I am currently working on a small project using ECS and DirectX12 and wanted to get some advice on if there is a "preferred" way or alternative ways to solving my issue.

Let me give a very basic layout to an entity which can be rendered

```
<entity  name = "Cube">
  <component = Transform ..blah blah>
  <component = Mesh = "cube.txt">  // holds data about verts/indicies etc.
  <component = Materials = "Mat1"> // holds data about the materials etc.
</entity>
```

### Approach 1

When the entities are loaded in, it would load each component. It gets to the mesh component and would now load in the mesh data and create the buffers needed and store them in the render system (by being able to get the render system from the world).

Say the next entity comes along and also wants the same mesh, it would check with the render system to see if it already exists and therefore would not need to load it in again but simply create a new copy for that entity.

### Approach 2

Before loading in entities the render system would have a list of meshes to load in upfront (this means some list which would need updating each time a new mesh wants to be included into the system).

Now when the entities are loaded in they can just have a tag to match the tag on the mesh in the render system.

---

I am not really sure whats the best approach with this as I started working with approach 1 and find the mesh component handles the loading which does seem a simple and straightforward approach, however I have not done anything like this ECS approach before and wanted to get advice as I may have overlooked a far more preferred approach which is more effective.

The concern I am keeping in mind for work to be done later is the ability to handle batching objects using the same mesh types PSO's etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that the first approach works for you right now, I'd say keep going with it until you need to definitively replace it with a system that can handle new functionality.

The second approach does sound like the "proper" way to do it, as in commercial game engines a list of assets is loaded in first on engine launch and most operations thereafter are carried out on the assumption of the mesh assets you need already existing (obviously not including things like procedural generation and so forth).